# Cursor gives "missing field" error, but doesn't say which field is missing

Tags: arcpy, cursor, fields-attributes

I am using a search cursor as follows:

```
fields = ["List", "of", "fields"]
FeatureClass = "path to a feature class, shapefile, xls, or dwg"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FeatureClass, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        stuff happens
```

and I am getting an error when searching an xls file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Workspace\Check.py", line 3, in <module>
    for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Failed to execute (Check).
```

And I get a similar error when searching a .shp file or feature class:

```
a column was specified that does not exist
```

I know from experience it is trying to tell me that a field in my file is missing, so my question is is there a way in the code to get it to tell me WHICH field is missing?  I get this error when using a search cursor on both .xls files and .dwg files, and I get a similar missing field error on .shp and feature classes sometimes.  I would like a general way for a search cursor missing a field to tell me which field I am missing.

Comment: Your error message doesn't line up with your title or your question.  "No value given for one or more required parameters" doesn't indicate "Missing field".  A missing field in a cursor gives a message like "A column was specified that does not exist".  Which line is line 173?  Is that `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor`?  Or is it `for row in cursor:`?

Comment: line 173 is 'for row in cursor:'  How should I format this question so that I only include the relavant part of a 400+ line script?  Edit the error message to match my code example, or just mention that it is part of a larger script?

Comment: Trim your code down into a test script to test *just* the cursor you are having problems with, then post that actual *tested* code snippet and error message.  Also please try not to sanitise the code too much as your pseudo code here may not contain errors that your actual code might

Comment: Although the overall script is long, this part hasn't been trimmed very much.  I have a searchable file, and a hard coded list of fields in it I want to search.  The error messages I get vary depending on the file type, but they are telling me that a field is missing or misspelled.  I would like to provide myself and my user a hint as to which field because there are typically a dozen of them I am searching on.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?  The error that a field doesn't exist is "A column was specified that does not exist" which is not the error you are getting

Comment: ArcGIS 10.3; and I should have specified that I get that error as well.  I believe the error I posted is because I am searching an excel file, I get "A column was specified that does not exist" when I have this error in shapefiles.  I know that both errors refer to the same thing because when I manually fix the fields after getting the first error it solves the problem.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include actual tested code.  Create a new test script on an XLS file and one on a feature class, and paste that actual tested code here, as well as the error messages.

Comment: How about using `ListFields` to list all the available fields, then there is no need for checking for missing fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check that all fields being used in your code actually exist in your feature class, try the following code:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Temp\mygdb.gdb\myFC"
fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]

fcFields = {fn.name.upper() for fn in arcpy.ListFields(fc)}
for f in fields:
    if f.upper() not in fcFields:
        print "field {} does not exist!".format(f)
```

Comment: I had it in my head that I could get the cursor to throw a more specific error somehow, but doing a pre-check makes more sense, thank you.